# Error: Could not find or load main class in Docker

Tags: java, docker, selenium, maven

I try to containerized my selenium code. In order to do the same I created a jar of my code that contains the .class file and dependencies.

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM ubuntu:18.
FROM openjdk:8u191-jre-alpine3.8
RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash procps
ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.3
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries
# Install Java.
#
RUN apk --update --no-cache add openjdk8 curl

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
&& curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache- maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
&& tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip- components=1 \
&& rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
&& ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV CLASSPATH /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/lib

  # Define default command.
CMD ["mvn", "--version"]

WORKDIR E:/Advanced_Selenium_Test_Automation_Framework-master
COPY target/AdavencedLevel.QDPM-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar AdavencedLevel.QDPM-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/E:/Advanced_Selenium_Test_Automation_Framework-master/AdavencedLevel.QDPM-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]
```

after running the docker image getting Error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class TestRunner
```

I try to set ENV through Dockerfile to avoid this issue
I am expecting that as jdk is already present in the Image then that issue should not occur.

Comment: I have never come across of two FROM entries in a dockerfile. What does this mean?

Comment: You sure you have such a lot of whitespaces in this path `AdavencedLevel.QDPM-    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`?

Comment: Those whitespaces while pasting , I did some edit in question

Comment: Two from for use base image with linux with java, BTW I am a beginner then please suggest the best. Thanks!

Comment: @MayankMishra, remove the first line `FROM ubuntu:18` because this makes no sense; your dockerfile can only be derived from one very image.

Comment: @kladderradatsch : did the same as you suggest but get the same result.

Comment: `TestRunner` comes from JUnit. I guess you've forgotten to include JUnit into your Jar file because in the `pom.xml` test libraries like Junit are declared normally with `<scope>test</scope>` so it is excluded from the Jar. When you need this library within the Jar make sure to remove the *test scope*.

Comment: I am using TestNG here.TestRunner is a class which has main method and the logic of maven invoker